# Windows 10 universal app writing to excel in C#

Tags: c#, excel, ms-office, win-universal-app

Is there a way to use Microsoft Office libraries to write to Excel. Looking for references or NuGet there doesn't seem to be something like that, as it is outside Universal app. Or am I missing something?

And if there isn't default way to do that, then what should I look into?

Comment: There are quite a few solutions to this.  Do you want to do this without Office installed?  If so, solutions like Closed XML (https://closedxml.codeplex.com/) are really nice.  Worst case, if you have Office installed, you can simply use Interop.

Comment: Also, check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/151005/create-excel-xls-and-xlsx-file-from-c-sharp

Answer (score 0):

You should use OpenXml to do this. Maybe this post answer you question. 
[open xml reading from excel file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23102010/open-xml-reading-from-excel-file)

Comment: Open XML is not WinRT compatible nor UWP compatible

Comment: Open XML is a Standard not a library. The hardest but possible way is to work directly with XML and zip.

Comment: Well, for SO that would mean adding some code then :) otherwise I think we would all assume you mean the Microsoft SDK for OpenXML - which is still not compatible at the moment.