# C# getting excel value date

Tags: c#, excel, date, datetime

I need to retrieve an excel column of date.
My first column 'A' values are formatted like this`6/20/2016 10:44`. I have no problem of retrieving column 'A' with this format using

```
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml;

double d = double.Parse(theCell.InnerText);
DateTime conv = DateTime.FromOADate(d).Date;
```

My second column 'B' is formatted as `6/20/2016.` With no time, just date.
but my problem is when i tried this code below:

```
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml;

double d = double.Parse(theCell.InnerText);
DateTime conv = DateTime.FromOADate(d).Date;
```

> theCell.InnerText value is 1455

I am having a different value. the value changes into `12/25/1903 12:00:00 AM`

How can I retrieve excel values with this kind of date format `6/30/2016` ?

Comment: Is the value in column B formatted as a date or is it actually a string?

Comment: Hi @dev1998 , thanks for checking my question. Column B are formatted as date.

Comment: It is all working for me, and I'm using the same 2 lines you are using. For the value that is wrong, what is the debugger showing for theCell.InnerText ?

Comment: if you put a breakpoint on the second set of code, what are the values of `theCell.InnerText` and `d`?  12/3/1909 is 3,265.  Somehow the text in that cell is rendering that value.  This sounds oversimplified, but it looks like you're not reading the cell you think you are reading.  I don't know OpenXml, but if you were using COM I'd have some suggestions to debug.

Comment: Hi @Hambone, i edited my question. Thanks for looking at it. I have done some research and couldnt find a solution to this problem using OpenXml.

Comment: Hi @dev1998, i have edited my question. Thanks for looking at it.

Comment: I posted my code. But I suspect @Hambone may be correct, you might be looking at the wrong cell.

Comment: Just a question...  can you use COM (interop)?  The only reason I would think no is if you don't have Excel on the machine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I located some code from here and modified it: [open xml reading from excel file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23102010/open-xml-reading-from-excel-file)

I am thinking the same thing that [Hambone](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1278553/hambone) is thinking, namely the Excel cell has something else in it, or you are not reading the cell you think you are.

Here is the code I am using, and it works for me:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet;



namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {

        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var filePath = @"c:\xyz\stack_c_Sharp.xlsx";
            using (var document = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(filePath, false))
            {
                var workbookPart = document.WorkbookPart;
                var workbook = workbookPart.Workbook;

                var sheets = workbook.Descendants<Sheet>();
                foreach (var sheet in sheets)
                {
                    var worksheetPart = (WorksheetPart)workbookPart.GetPartById(sheet.Id);
                    var sharedStringPart = workbookPart.SharedStringTablePart;

                    string text;
                    var rows = worksheetPart.Worksheet.Descendants<Row>();
                    foreach (var row in rows)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine();
                        int count = row.Elements<Cell>().Count();

                        foreach (Cell theCell in row.Elements<Cell>())
                        {

                            text = theCell.CellValue.InnerText;

                            double d = double.Parse(theCell.InnerText);
                            DateTime conv = DateTime.FromOADate(d).Date;

                            Console.Write(text + " ");
                            Console.Write(conv + " ");

                        }
                    }
                }
                Console.ReadLine();
            }


        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had opened the file while I was debugging on VS2022 and I had your same problem. Try closing the file.