# "IOException was unhandled" that error keeps appearing

Tags: vb.net

Im having this problem and it doesnt seem to go away. Theres a code ive done in vb.net, in which i to to stream files but i keep on getting that error

> "IOException was unhandled" The process cannot access the file
>   'C:\Users\Lenovo\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\File
>   streaming\File Streaming\bin\Debug\banking.xls' because it is being
>   used by another process.

Heres the code:

```
Imports System.IO

Imports System.Windows.Forms.Form
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnDisplay_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnDisplay.Click

        Dim FileStr As New FileStream("banking.xls", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)

        Dim a As New StreamWriter(FileStr)

        'a.WriteLine("File should be displayed in the RTB............")
        'a.Close()

       **ERROR APPEARS HERE**     
        FileStr = New FileStream("banking.xls", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)

        Dim i As New StreamReader(FileStr)

        i.BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin)

        If i.Peek() > -1 Then

            rtbDisplay.Text &= i.ReadLine()

        End If
        i.Close()

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnClear_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnClear.Click

        rtbDisplay.Text = ""

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnExit_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnExit.Click

        Me.Close()

    End Sub

    Private Function FileStream() As Object
        Throw New NotImplementedException
    End Function

End Class
```

Comment: Where is there C++?

Comment: sorry theres no c++, or i think. Im still new so i wouldnt know to be exact

Comment: Put your streams in Using statement to make sure everything is closed properly. Sometime having the same file open causes a problem. Is there an other process that tries to open the file?

Comment: Do you have the file open in Excel?

Comment: the_lotus im trying to understand what exactly it is that you saying, remember im very very new to vb

Comment: Steve the file is not open.

Comment: [`Using` statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/using-statement)

Comment: But the file *is* open with `Dim a As New StreamWriter(FileStr)`

Answer (score 2):

`FileStream` and `StreamWriter` are IDisposable objects, and should be disposed when you are done with them. when IDisposable have local scope, it is good practice to create them with a `Using` block.

```
Sub Main()
    Using FileStr As New FileStream("banking.xls", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)
        Using a As New StreamWriter(FileStr)
            a.WriteLine("File should be displayed in the RTB............")
        End Using
    End Using

    Using FileStr = New FileStream("banking.xls", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
        Dim i As New StreamReader(FileStr)
    End Using
End Sub
```

Still, I don't know why you are writing text to an xls file like this. If you are manipulating Excel files, you should look at [Open Xml](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23102010/832052) or [Microsoft Office Interop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23102523/832052)

Comment: Mostly I agree about Open Xml or Interop. Sometimes, though, you can do an "excel lite" effect by working with a tab-delimited text file that has an xls extension. Excel will open this and treat it as a native file. You just need to be careful, because once the real Excel saves new info to that file, you're dealing with the full Excel format.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn interesting. I work a lot with tab delim txt and *Open with >> Excel* often. After a quick test, you are right that it works with xls extension, though there's a warning message when opening the file. It doesn't work with the newer xlsx extension however.

Comment: Id really appreciate your help with what you just mentioned! i have no clue as to what you are saying. im still new in this field