# C# WebApplication - System.Data.OleDb found but nearly empty

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, api, oledb

I am currently trying to read from an Excel file with OleDB.

This is the Code:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Text;

namespace WebApplication1.My_Logic.Worker
{
    public class ExcelLoader
    {
        private string GetConnectionString()
        {
            Dictionary<string, string> props = new Dictionary<string, string>();

            props["Provider"] = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;";
            props["Extended Properties"] = "Excel 12.0 XML";
            props["Data Source"] = "C:\\MyExcel.xlsx";

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> prop in props)
            {
                sb.Append(prop.Key);
                sb.Append('=');
                sb.Append(prop.Value);
                sb.Append(';');
            }

            return sb.ToString();
        }

        private DataSet ReadExcelFile()
        {
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            string connectionString = GetConnectionString();
            using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
            {
                conn.Open();
                OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
                cmd.Connection = conn;

                // Get all Sheets in Excel File
                DataTable dtSheet = conn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);

                // Loop through all Sheets to get data
                foreach (DataRow dr in dtSheet.Rows)
                {
                    string sheetName = dr["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();

                    if (!sheetName.EndsWith("$"))
                        continue;

                    // Get all rows from the Sheet
                    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [" + sheetName + "]";

                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    dt.TableName = sheetName;

                    OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
                    da.Fill(dt);

                    ds.Tables.Add(dt);
                }

                cmd = null;
                conn.Close();
            }

            return ds;
        }
    }
}
```

`System.Data.OleDb` is greyd out (not used) and following classes cannot be found:

```
OleDbCommand
OleDbConnection
OleDbSchemaGuid
OleDbDataAdapter
```

When i look into the `System.Data.OleDb` there are only 2 classes shown by Visual Studio:

```
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbPermission
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbPermissionAttribute
```

Everywhere i read in the internet the only anwser was to add `using System.Data.OleDb` but i do have it and Visual Studio seems to know it.

Its a freshly generated ASP.NET Core 2.1 API Project from Visual Studio 2017.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OleDb is not available in .NET Core since it's not implemented for other platforms rather than windows.

See the following github [thread](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/23542).

If you want to read from xlsx just use [OpenXmlSdk](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-XML-SDK/tree/master/src/DocumentFormat.OpenXml) which is cross platform and supported by .NET core.

See how to read excel file using OpenXmlSdk in the following [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23104151/1099716).