# How to read Excel file (Header only) data

Tags: c#, excel

I want to read data from column headers of an excel.
Each excel file have same header name but header names are in different rows.
Please help me out in c# Code.
My Code is below.

```
 var textfile = Request.Files[0];
        string profileimage = Path.GetExtension(textfile.FileName);           
        string ProfileName = path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(textfile.FileName);
        IExcelDataReader excelReader;     
     excelReader=ExcelReaderFactory.CreateBinaryReader(textfile.InputStream);
         DataSet result = excelReader.AsDataSet();
         DataTable dt = result.Tables[0];
         int Tcount = dt.Rows.Count;
         for (int i = 2; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {}
```

...

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please show code which you have implemented till now.

Comment: Edit Done .check my question please

Answer (score 2):

Try to use OpenXML SDK. Here you can find more information about:

1. [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23102010/open-xml-reading-from-excel-file)
2. [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/how-to-get-a-column-heading-in-a-spreadsheet)
3. [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Open-XML-SDK/2.7.2)
4. [GitHub](https://github.com/officedev/open-xml-sdk)

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use Interop. This comes with office, so you won't need any third party stuff. But be ware that in order **TO USE INTEROP YOU NEED OFFICE INSTALLED** on the system that runs the application.

```
using Excel=Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
```

```
// Start Excel.exe
MyApp = new Excel.Application();
// Hide the visual application, you can also choose to omit this to show the excel application while your code works on it.
MyApp.Visible = false;
// Open the file
MyBook = MyApp.Workbooks.Open("Some/Excel/File");
// Get the first sheet
MySheet = MyBook.Sheets[1];
// Get some cell value
MyCell= MySheet.Cells[rowIndex,colIndex]
```

Then you can itterate over the rows to find the header by either row/column index or string comparison.
At last you need to release the COM objects with this (order is important here), or the Excel.exe will keep running:

```
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(MyCell);
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(MySheet);
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(MyBook);
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(MyApp);
```

Just make sure to read documentation first, since there are some gotchas when working with interop, like releasing the objects.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158706/how-do-i-properly-clean-up-excel-interop-objects

Comment: It is not really good idea because Interop need installed Office.